# What do you suggest to use between Clamav and Sophos?

Tags: security, antivirus, clamav

I know Ubuntu does not need of antivirus, but if i transfer some files in Windows it should be good idea to scan the files. I saw many positive reviews about Clamav and Sophos. What do you suggest to install? Clamav, Sophos or both? I thought to install both, but i afraid that they can be conflict. If i install both, can they to be in conflict?
About the privacy, do Clamav or Sophos gather information about the files that they scan?
P.S sorry for my bad english

Comment: `I know Ubuntu does not need of antivirus` ... Why not? And this is very opinion base I guess. Having two AVs installed always can lead to conflicts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but if i transfer some files in Windows it should be good idea to scan the files

That is almost the only valid reason to use a virus scanner on Linux. If it is for Windows files you can stick with 1 up-to-date virus scanner. Those scanners do an amazing job on Windows files and will pick up all viruses when the definition of a virus is there.

> If i install both, can they to be in conflict?

You can install both. Thing is: both will claim as much resources to work with as they can so using both at the same time is not the smartest thing to do.

For scanning Linux files I would always install 2: update the definitions regularly, use one automatically and the other manually. When the 1st sets of an alarm, stop it and scan manually with the 2nd one, compare notices and dismiss all notices one and not the other reports. Those will be false positives (if they are both up-to-date). What remains should be investigated. You can do the same for Windows files.

> About the privacy, do Clamav or Sophos gather information about the files that they scan?

Not from what I have seen.